# Сайт не во весь размер

Tags: android, css

На платформе андроид когда захожу на сайт он отображается не в полный экран, т.е. по бокам есть место, как это исправить на css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы бы показали сайт. Причин может быть масса.
Например, для мобильных нужно прописывать специальный мета-тэг:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

У вас такой прописан?

Comment: К сожалению нет, он на локальном компьютере. когда это сделал, все очень слишком увеличилось и картинки стали размыты

Comment: хотя бы код приведите тогда, погадаем.

Comment: я не могу сюда, слишком мало места, можно вам в другое место написать?

Comment: когда нет возможности или желания показывать целиком сайт, или нужно привести маленький пример кода, можно воспользоваться замечательным сервисом jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d8qh7/ там работает так как я и хочу, но в андроде, вряд ли

Comment: для body есть margin: auto, но ширина не указана.
Укажите для мобильных ширину 100%:

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        body { width: 100%;
    }

и скажите: сеанс телепатии удался?

Comment: Вполне) если только ответите почему max-width: 767px и не будут ли размыты картинки, потому что пробую через емулятор опери мини есть некая не чёткость

Comment: 767 — это традиционно считается граница между шириной смартфона и шириной планшета.
Картинки должны быть чёткими, предлагаю посмотреть на настоящем андроиде, а не на эмуляторе. К тому же на андроидах всё же чаще хром, чем опера мини.